# Get arbitary request header value in golang fasthttp

Tags: http, parsing, go, header, fasthttp

Searched through docs and read source, could not find anyway to access something like

`ctx.Request.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")`

I see in `header.go`, the `type RequestHeader struct` is defined something like

```
h     []argsKV
bufKV argsKV

cookies []argsKV

rawHeaders []byte
```

Is it possible to access these fields without reflection at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found it.

```
ctx.Request.Header.Peek("X-Forwarded-For")
```